# How can QGIS 3 Data Source Manager automatically close after load a layer?

Tags: qgis-3

In previous QGIS version, after load whatever layer, Data Source Manager automatically closed. However, in QGIS 3, as it can be observed at following image, Data Source Manager remains open afterward load, e.g., a raster layer. It is necessary to close it manually.

[image]

I could not find any useful in Settings Options Menu. How can QGIS 3 Data Source Manager automatically close after load a layer?

**Editing Note:**

I can add multiple layers at once in this way (by using previous **Open GDAL/OGR supported dataset(s)**):

[image]

[image]

I closed **Data Source Manager** quickly with **Esc** key. So, best option is given by @Steven Kay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are keyboard shortcuts available which let you close / dismiss a dialog. You still need to close it manually, though, but it might be faster  or easier for some.

Pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key seems to dismiss the dialog on both Mac and Ubuntu. Allegedly this should work on Windows too, but can't confirm. On the Mac can also use <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>Period</kbd>

Alternatively there's the Browser dock window, which can also be used outside of the Data Source Manager.

I've just noticed this has a search bar (click on the Filter icon). It's also available in 2.18 - but it only searches folders you've added to 'Favourites'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It isn't my desired answer but **Esc** key works well because my index finger of left hand is always near this key. I don't need to move mouse cursor with right hand.

Comment: I can confirm the **Esc** key closes the Data Source Manager on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

This change was motivated by the idea that users commonly add multiple layers at once, particularly during the start of creating a project. Therefore, it is useful to keep the dialog open.

As far as I remember, no option to change this behavior has been added.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but to add multiple layers at once I don't need to keep the **Data Source Manager** still open. I can do that selection at once in **Open GDAL/OGR supported dataset(s)**.

Comment: By the way, the ordering of the add/close buttons in this dialogue is irritating (at least on Windows): The first, most important action (add) is not far left as one is used to from other applications. Am I the only one who always accidentally clicks close instead of add?

Comment: @Mesa please open tickets on the bug tracker for usability problems